# Linking in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am quite new to Laravel but I've watched quite a lot of tutorials to get into it, so I am used to it now. However, I am stuck at a point where I want to link to a users favorites in one of my blade.php files.

This is the link in my bootstrap navbar:

```
<li><a href="{{ URL::to('users/' . $user->id . '/favortites' }}"><i class="fa fa-heart">    </i> Favorites</a></li>
```

I have tried using URL::to but it does not work. I am not sure whether I am implementing the userId correctly.

In the end the link I want to access should look like this: users/5/favorites if the user with an id of 5 is the authenticated user.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML::linkAction /

have a look at the docs for more :)

laravel helpers

Answer (score 8):

There are several options. You can use the `link_to_action` / `HTML::linkAction` helper if you're linking to a controller's method:

```
<li>{{ HTML::linkAction('UserController@getFavorites', 'Favorites', ['id' => 5], ['class' => 'abc']) }}</li>
```

Another option is to link to a named route with `link_to_route` / `HTML::linkRoute`:

```
 <li>{{ HTML::linkRoute('user.favorites', 'Favorites', ['id' => 5], ['class' => 'abc']) }}</li>
```

You can find more information on helpers in the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls) and in the API pages for [HtmlBuilder](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Html/HtmlBuilder.html) and [UrlGenerator](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.html).

Comment: how to pass a get value in blade link? i mean what if I want something like this
    <a href="go/to/url.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">Click</a>